# How can I delete a related middle entity record without triggering a ConcurrencyException?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, datatables, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to delete from EF Core generated SQL Server DB rendered ASP.NET MVC 5 with C# and DataTables.

At first I was able to successfully delete a middle related table record across a 3 table relationship. But after restarting the session I get this error upon trying to delete.

```
> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1
> row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or
> deleted since entities were loaded. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on
> understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
```

These are the tables I am using. I am trying to delete a record in the Registration entity.

[image: Photo of the tables involved]

I have checked to see if the deletion is occurring in the backend when I step over the code and it is but the result is not being sent to the database when I'm on this line in method UnassignUserRegistration(int RegistrationID).

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I will show you my code now. Please let me know if there is any related code you need me to show to help resolve the issue or if I have put too much in not related to the problem, thanks.

UPDATE: 3/8/21 Added models for User and Job and TeamContext.

**JobController.cs**

```
    public IActionResult GetAssignedUsers()
    {
         _context.Jobs.OrderByDescending(j => j.ID).FirstOrDefault();       
         var userlist = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Registrations.Any());
         return Json(userlist);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Opens up the UserAssignments view page, using the
    /// currently selected JobID in memory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ID"></param>
    /// <returns>The currently selected Job in memory</returns>
    public IActionResult UserAssignments(int? ID)
    {
        if (ID == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var job = _context.Jobs.Find(ID);
        return View(job);
    }
    
    //TO DO: Fix method.
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UnassignUserRegistration(int RegistrationID)
    {
        Registration registration = new Registration{ID = RegistrationID};
        _context.Registrations.Remove(registration).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(UserAssignments), new{ID = RegistrationID});
    }
```

**Registration model**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Pitcher.Models
{
    public class Registration
    {
        public int ID {get;set;}
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int JobID { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "User Start Date")]
        [Column("RegistrationDate")]
        public DateTime RegistrationDate {get;set;}        
        public User User {get;set;}
        public Job Job {get;set;}
    }
}
```

**Job model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Pitcher.Models
{
    public class Job
    {        
        
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Job Title must be bettween 3 to 20 characters.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
        [Column("JobTitle")]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Job Description must be bettween 200 to 3 characters.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [Column("JobDescription")]
        public string JobDescription { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = " Start Date")]
        [Column("JobStartDate")]
        public DateTime JobStartDate {get;set;}

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Deadline Date")]
        [Column("JobDeadlineDate")]
        public DateTime JobDeadline {get;set;}

        [Display(Name = "Job Is Complete?")]
        [Column("JobIsComplete")]
        public bool JobIsComplete{get;set;}

        public ICollection<Registration> Registrations {get;set;}

        public ICollection<Result> Results {get;set;}
    }   
}
```

**User model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Pitcher.Models;
namespace Pitcher.Models
{
    public class User
    {      
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "* First Name be bettween 2 to 20 characters.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [Column("UserFirstName")]
        public string UserFirstName { get; set; }   

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "* Last Name be bettween 2 to 30 characters.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [Column("UserLastName")]
        public string UserLastName { get; set; }        
                
        [Required]
        [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Email address must be bettween 3 to 30 characters.")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [Column("UserContactEmail")]
        public string UserContactEmail{get;set;}      
        
        // [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        [Phone()]
        [Column("UserPhoneNumber")]
        public string UserPhoneNumber{get;set;}
        
        [StringLength(37,ErrorMessage = "Address cannot be longer than 37 characters.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        [Column("UserAddress")]
        public string UserAddress{get;set;}
        
        //This regular expression allows valid postcodes and not just USA Zip codes.        
        [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
        [Column("UserPostCode")][DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        public string UserPostCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15,ErrorMessage = "Country cannot be longer than 15 characters.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        [Column("UserCountry")] 
        public string UserCountry {get;set;}
        
        
        [Phone()]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
        [Column("UserMobileNumber")]
        public string UserMobileNumber {get;set;}

        [StringLength(3,ErrorMessage = "State cannot be longer than 3 characters.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        [Column("UserState")]
        public string UserState {get;set;}           
        
        public string UserFullname => string.Format("{0} {1}", UserFirstName, UserLastName);

        public ICollection<Registration> Registrations {get;set;}
    }
}
```

**TeamContext**

```
using Pitcher.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pitcher.Models.TeamViewModels;
namespace Pitcher.Data
{
    public class TeamContext : DbContext
    {
        public TeamContext(DbContextOptions<TeamContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Registration> Registrations {get;set;}
        public DbSet<Job> Jobs {get;set;}     

        
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("tblUser");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>().ToTable("tblRegistration");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().ToTable("tblJob");
        }        
    }
}
```

**UserAssignments.cshtml view table code**

```
<h3>Assigned Users</h3>
<table id="registeredUsersTable" style="display: none">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => user.UserFirstName)
            </th>        
            <th>
               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => user.UserLastName)
            </th>
            <th>
               @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => user.UserContactEmail)
            </th>
            <th>                
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @if(user == null)
    {
         <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Model empty");
        </script>        
    }
    else
    {
        <tbody></tbody>
    }
</table>
    document.getElementById('registeredUsersTable').style.display = 'block';
        var id=@Model.ID 
        $('#registeredUsersTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
            'type': 'get',
            'data': { ID: id},
            'dataType': "json",                  
            "url": "@Url.Action("GetAssignedUsers")",
            "dataSrc": function (result) {
                return result;
                }
            },            
            "columns": [                
            { "data": "userFirstName"},
            { "data": "userLastName"},
            { "data": "userContactEmail"},
            {
            "data": null,
            "render": function (value) {
                return  '<a href="/Jobs/UnassignUserRegistration?RegistrationID=' + value.id + '"button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Unassign</a>';
            }
                }
            ]
        });
```

Comment: That's a many-to-many relation, not a `middle entity` and modifying it doesn't cause concurrency conflicts. You code *doesn't* remove the entity though, it attaches a new object with only partial data. When EF tries to save it, it will detect that the data doesn't match and assume there's a concurrency conflict. If you want to avoid loading the entity, *don't* use EF. Otherwise you *have* to load the entity and delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem with the UnassignUserRegistration method was that I misinterpreted the RegistrationID as the actual ID being passed in.

When I hover over the unassign button that contains that method I could see the URL and that the function was expecting the UserID and the JobID and not the RegistrationID.

The fix involved me putting into the parameters of the method the UserID and the JobID and then using the .Single method to return
both UserID and JobID.

Then I redirect to action just the JobID as that's all that is needed.

I then in the view just had to return.

```
UserID=' + value.id + '&JobID=' + id +'
```

And no errors occurred after that.

**JobController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> UnassignUserRegistration(int UserID, int JobID)
{
    Registration registration = _context.Registrations.Single(c => c.UserID == UserID && c.JobID == JobID);     
    _context.Entry(registration).State = EntityState.Deleted; 
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                             
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(UserAssignments), new{ID = JobID});
}
```

**UserAssignments.cshtml**

```
document.getElementById('registeredUsersTable').style.display = 'block';    
$('#registeredUsersTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {                 
    "url": "@Url.Action("GetAssignedUsers")",
    "dataSrc": function (result) {
        return result;
        }
    },            
    "columns": [                
    { "data": "userFirstName"},
    { "data": "userLastName"},
    { "data": "userContactEmail"},
    {
    "data": null,
    "render": function (value) {
        return  'Unassign';
    }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't remove the `Registration` entity, it attaches a new object with only partial data and tries to persist it in the `Removed` state, thus deleting it.

```
Registration registration = new Registration{ID = RegistrationID};
_context.Registrations.Remove(registration).State = EntityState.Deleted;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

EF uses *all* property values to detect whether the data was modified and obviously, the `UserID`, `JobId` and `RegistrationDate` don't match the stored data, so the operation fails.

Instead of attaching a new empty object, load the current object and delete it :

```
var registration = _context.Registrations.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.ID=RegistrationID);
if (registration!=null)
{
    _context.Registrations.Remove(registration);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

If you don't want to load the entity you'll have to execute the DELETE SQL query directly. In EF 6 you can use [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Database_ExecuteSqlCommand_System_String_System_Object___) :

```
var sql="DELETE tblRegistration where ID=@p0";
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql,RegistrationId);
```

EF is an ORM, not a generic data access library. Its job is to translate object operations to database operations. It can translate `Remove(someEntity)` to `DELETE` on that specific entity,  but it's not meant to generate a `DELETE` directly. This is the job of the underlying data access library, ADO.NET. The `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` offers a way to execute an arbitrary parameterized SQL command using ADO.NET without having to explicitly construct and configure the DbCommand object.

**EF Core**

There's no difference in EF Core. Before an entity can be deleted using the ORM itself it must be loaded.

The only thing that changes is the name of the methods used to execute a direct SQL command. They're named [ExecuteSqlRawAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlrawasync?view=efcore-5.0), with its blocking counterpart `ExecuteSqlRaw` and [ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlinterpolatedasync?view=efcore-5.0) with the blocking `ExecuteSqlInterpolated`.

The difference is that `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` uses a raw SQL string with parameter placeholders, while `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` can treat an interpolated string as a parameterized SQL string :

```
var sql="DELETE tblRegistration where ID=@id";
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql,id);
```

or

```
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(
      "DELETE tblRegistration where ID={id});
```

In this case, instead of generating a SQL string that could contain malicious content, `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync("DELETE tblRegistration where ID={id})` creates a parameterized query with a parameter and passes the `id` value as the value of that parameter.

The page [Using Raw SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) explains how parameters are used, especially with interpolated strings, and why interpolated strings should *only* be used with the `Interpolated` methods to avoid SQL injection. Too many people were using string interpolation to inject values into the query, introducing SQL injection vulnerabilities, so two separate methods were created that make it clear what is going on at each case.

Comment: thx for info, using .net5 "core" until support dies which would need to be upgraded should I use EF 6. Code where you load current object and delete doesn't compile. The first line here.

var registration = _context.Registrations.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.ID=RegistrationID);

returns error at col 61 just during the first r to end of RegistrationID. Error says. 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' [Pitcher]
Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type [Pitcher]

Comment: Also sorry if I didn't make it clear but I am using .NET 5 no longer called "Core" anymore and Entity Framework Core 
5.0.0. Not Entity Framework.

Comment: @JordanNash there's no difference. If you want to delete an entity using EF Core, you have to load it first. Otherwise, you need to use `ExecuteSqlRaw` or `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` to execute a raw SQL command

Answer (score 0):

Based on the table structure, the User and Job contain many to many relationships, So I create the following models:

```
[Table("tblJob")]
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime JobStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime JobDeadlineDate { get; set; }
    public bool JobIsComplete { get; set; }

    public List<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }
}
[Table("tblUser")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserAddress { get; set; }
    public string UserPostCode { get; set; }
    public string UserCountry { get; set; }
    public string UserMobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserState { get; set; }
    public List<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }

}
[Table("tblRegistration")]
public class Registration
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int JobID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "User Start Date")]
    [Column("RegistrationDate")]
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the ApplicationDBContext.cs, configure the many to many relationships:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public new DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>()
            .HasKey(t => t.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.User)
            .WithMany(p => p.Registrations)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.UserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Job)
            .WithMany(t => t.Registrations)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.JobID);
    }
}
```

Then, add the following test data:

[image]

To delete the related entities, you could use the following code:

```
var user = _context.Users.Include(c => c.Registrations).FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == 1);

foreach (var item in user.Registrations)
{
    _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted; //delete items from the Join table(registrations).
}
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted; //delete the user //
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Then, the result as below:

[image]

If you don't want to remove the user, try to comment or delete this line: `_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted;`

Comment: The article you point as reference uses `Remove` in all examples. What's the point of trying to treat *tracked* entities as if they were detached?

Comment: Besides, the OP didn't ask for a cascade delete. Deleting a Registration isn't meant to delete users and jobs. It wouldn't do so in SQL either - the direction of the FK relation is from the *user* to the registration, not the other way. Deleting a Registration isn't supposed to delete a User

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, Thanks for reminding me about that, I have updated my reply.

Comment: Hi @ZhiLv. Thanks for going through all that effort but if you asked I would have provided the models. and context. Just wasn't sure if it was going to scare off people from helping me solve problem. Your code will not work with my project unfortunately as I am using a much more simplistic context class called `TeamContext.cs`. Also in `User.cs` I  notice you use a list for Registrations navigation property. I use ICollection.

Comment: Hi again @ZhiLv. My god it seems to finally delete the registration record successfully! The only problem now is when I delete a registration record and return it with this  `return RedirectToAction(nameof(UserAssignments), new{ID = RegistrationID});` it will report NullReferenceException as C# goes to the last curly brace in method and error is reported on `var id=@Model.ID` in UserAssignments.chstml.  But if I go back on the browser it will still show that it has being deleted. What I would like to do now is somehow catch the error so the user can't see it but I can't because of the return.

Comment: Hi @JordanNash, according to your code, after deleting the record, it will redirect to the UserAssignments action method, in this method I assume you will find the record based on the id, if that is the case, you could check whether the result is null, if it is null return a null prompt message to the view page. Besides, you could also check whether the returned model is null or not in the view page, use `@if` statement.

Comment: _check whether the result is null, if it is null return a null prompt message to the view page._ It's not null. I have never done null prompts on cshtml files. The funny thing is as I step through the code RegistrationID matches and I see all the user properties from the correctly selected User entity. The Job entity is returning null and not showing me it's related entity properties. I don't know if that matters or not as the JobID is present and correct, reporting the value of 2.
If it's the fault of the null Job entity then how do I include entity's properties at the same time as user?

Comment: Still need help. I did what you said and added the @if statement which in my question to check if model null. It's not null at all. Only UserID 2 and 4 will be deleted without error. 1 and 3 will return a NullReferenceException and I don't understand why it even does that.  Here is a copy of the tblRegistration data where I'm getting some of the data from.
ID UserID JobID RegistrationDate
3036 1 2 2021-08-06 00:02:18
5042 2 2 2021-08-10 22:58:51
5044 4 2 2021-08-10 22:59:03
5045 3 2 2021-08-10 22:59:11
The rest are from tblUser which contain the UserContactEmail field.